# meaning of p in %pa[p] in the printk formats

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, device-driver

The question is with regard to the printk formats. The documentation that I'm reading is located [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt)

Here is an excerpt that I'm asking about:

```
Physical addresses types phys_addr_t:

    %pa[p]  0x01234567 or 0x0123456789abcdef

    For printing a phys_addr_t type (and its derivatives, such as
    resource_size_t) which can vary based on build options, regardless of
    the width of the CPU data path. Passed by reference.
```

What does `[p]` in `%pa[p]` stand for? What does it mean?

Comment: I guess this means 'you can use either `%pa` either `%pap`'. Those might be two options, and the output (`0x...`) provided to the right may be the output each of these options provides (perhaps the last one gives longer (more precise?) output). But that's only a guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `p` in `[p]` stands for *`phys_addr_t`* when used in `%pap`. This is analogous to the `d` in `%pad` stands for *`dma_addr_t`*, as seen in the cited document:

```
DMA addresses types dma_addr_t:

    %pad    0x01234567 or 0x0123456789abcdef

    For printing a dma_addr_t type which can vary based on build options,
    regardless of the width of the CPU data path. Passed by reference.
```

Since it provides no documented difference between `%pa` and `%pap`, it means that they behave the same. The contents inside the brackets indicate optional modifiers. This is seen in the definition of `%*pE` later in the document:

```
Raw buffer as an escaped string:

    %*pE[achnops]
...
    The conversion rules are applied according to an optional combination
    of flags (see string_escape_mem() kernel documentation for the
    details):
        a - ESCAPE_ANY
        c - ESCAPE_SPECIAL
        h - ESCAPE_HEX
        n - ESCAPE_NULL
        o - ESCAPE_OCTAL
        p - ESCAPE_NP
        s - ESCAPE_SPACE
    By default ESCAPE_ANY_NP is used.
```